# Making a SQL query (cross table)

Tags: sql, join

I am revising for my exam and I am a bit struggling with SQL queries..

Task for me is:

> *write a SQL query to list the full names of all the clients that
>   attend Allen Moore‟s classes, in alphabetical order of surname (i.e.
>   Lname column)*

**Client**

```
Cid Fname Lname Fitness
C129 Julie Summer 1
C525 Max Hedrum 3
C628 John Long 3
C772 Warren Peace 2
C829 Anna Heart 2
```

**Programme**

```
Code Title Fitness
AR02 Aerobics 2
EN99 Endurance 3
TU10 Tune-Up 1
UB01 Upper-Body 2
YG02 Yoga 1
```

**Staff**

```
Sid Fname Lname Position Salary
S09 Jenny Sayer Psychologist 23500
S22 Allen Moore Instructor 21500
S28 Polly Purves Instructor 19000
S35 Jim Shoe Instructor 18000
S55 Mark Spencer Manager 25500
```

**Class**

```
Code Sid Cid
AR02 S35 C772
EN99 S22 C525
TU10 S35 C129
UB01 S28 C628
YG02 S22 C829
YG02 S22 C12
```

Is it something like:

```
SELECT Cliente.Fname, Cliente.Lname
FROM Staff, Class, Cliente
WHERE  Staff.Sid = Class.Sid AND Staff.Fname = "Allen" AND Staff.Lname = "Moore 
AND Class.Cid = Cliente.Cid
GROUP BY Cliente.lName ASC;
```

Thanks!

Comment: You will want to use 'order by' instead of 'group by'. And it is better to use joins specifically instead of all in the from.

Comment: Not fair down-voting this - the question is simple but reasonable, and effort was put into finding an answer.

Comment: There's a minor issue with Cliente (French?) vs Client in the table name.  The GROUP BY is not correct (it should list both columns because they are not aggregates, and then it doesn't do any harm except probably slow things down a little; it does not guarantee the output order; with one column, it is just wrong).  And your code does not use the more modern (as in, since 1992) standard SQL join notations.  However, apart from these niggles, the query will work, I believe, as written.  You have a number of suggestions for how to write the query with explicit joins in amongst the answers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you can respond with a vote up.

Comment: @vikrantislav: I did, but there was still a deficit.  Someone else has agreed with me and cancelled the deficit.  And explaining why heads off further down-votes, which (combined with I couldn't get the score to zero) is why I commented on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GROUP BY in your query has to go, you don't have to aggregate anything. I would prefer the SQL92 syntax for a join:

```
SELECT 
    Client.Fname, Client.Lname
FROM 
   Staff
INNER JOIN
Class ON Staff.Sid = Class.Sid AND Staff.Fname = "Allen" AND Staff.Lname = "Moore"
INNER JOIN 
Client ON Class.Cid = Cliente.Cid
ORDER BY Cliente.lName ASC;
```

Comment: Strictly, the GROUP BY is unnecessary but does no harm other than perhaps slow the query down.  However, it is not the same as an ORDER BY clause and does not guarantee that the data will be presented in a sorted order.  (It might also matter if there are two different staff members called "Jane Doe".)

Comment: @jonathan leffler: the group by as used in the question does a lot uf harm, since the column list must not contain columns without any aggregate function, which are not a part of the group by clause.

Comment: Ah - fair comment.  MySQL would let you get away with it, but Standard SQL (all the other DBMS) would not.  My bad.

Comment: Thank You, now I understand this type of queering.

Answer (score 2):

```
select c.fname + ' ' + c.lname
from Client c
inner join Class cl
on c.cid = cl.cid
inner join Staff s
on s.sid = cl.sid
where s.fname = 'allen'
and s.lname = 'moore'
order by c.lname
```

Comment: If you are going to cheat and do the lookup of Allen Moore's staff ID, you don't need to join with the Staff table.  If you replace the WHERE clause with `WHERE s.Fname = "Allen" AND S.Lname = "Moore"` then you'd be clean and the join with Staff is needed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good point, fixed.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Using different aliases and a more popular convention for JOINs, but your query should also work. Also, ORDER BY ascending is default, so ASC is optional...

```
SELECT CLNT.Fname, CLNT.Lname
FROM Class AS CLS
     INNER JOIN Client AS CLNT ON CLS.Cid = CLNT.Cid
     INNER JOIN Staff AS S ON CLS.Sid = S.Sid
WHERE S.Fname = 'Allen'
      AND S.Lname = 'Moore'
ORDER BY CLNT.Lname;
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. This is basically the same as Mithrandir's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try brushing up on your use of the JOIN...ON clause.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the information from other tables is actually being used, why JOIN at all?

```
 SELECT FName, LName
 FROM Client
 WHERE
    Cid IN (
        SELECT Cid
        FROM Class
        WHERE Sid = (
            SELECT Sid FROM Staff WHERE FName = 'Allen' AND LName = 'Moore'
        )
    )
 ORDER BY LName ASC;
```

Comment: Your query is isomorphic with one written using explicit joins, and a good optimizer will treat them as the same.  What you've got will certainly work.